# How to display an image with Django HTML?

Tags: html, django

So i've managed to create a web page that displays correctly when run, however images just dont work.
My directory goes like this:

polls/
   mountain.jpg
   templates/
      polls/
          index.html
   .everything else
I'm trying to use this code in index.html to display mountain.jpg.

what am i doing wrong?

```
<h1 style="font-size:50px;line-height:20px;color:rgb(145,0,0);font-family: Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif"></h1>
<h2 style="line-height:10px;color:rgb(140,140,140)"></h2>
<h3 style="font-size:40px;line-height:10px;font-family: Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif"></h3>
<body style="background-color:rgb(255,239,154)"></body>
<!--Style placeholders-->

<h2>Mountain</h2>
<img src="mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

***UPDATE***
I managed to solve the problem. Follow this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: Do you know anything about static files in Django? And can you add some code?

Comment: I Don't know much about Django. I added the code to the Origional post

Answer (score 0):

***SOLUTION***
I managed to find a guide explaining how to get this working, thanks to Q-bart. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/